# ComboBox text property only updates on second function call

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, combobox, flash-cs5

I am attempting to change the text of a ComboBox immediately after enabling it. However, the text does not appear to update until the function is called for a second time (in this case, when the button is pressed a second time). A trace() during the function reveals that the text property does change the first time, but the change is not visible on the screen until the second time this function is called.

Here's a test case which should illustrate the problem when pasted into the first frame of a new project in Flash CS5:

```
import flash.events.Event;
import fl.controls.Button;
import fl.controls.ComboBox;

stop()

var btn_test:Button = new Button()
var cb_test:ComboBox = new ComboBox()

this.addChild(btn_test)
this.addChild(cb_test)

btn_test.x = 100
cb_test.enabled = false

btn_test.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, setText)

function setText(evt:Event)
{
    cb_test.enabled = true
    cb_test.textField.text = "foo"
    trace(cb_test.textField.text)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you can try UIComponent.validateNow() method. As fl.controls.UIComponent decides to cache property changes, and sometimes overreacts, you might try forcing it to render with `cb_test.validateNow();`

Comment: Thanks, this worked when placing `cb_test.validateNow()` in between enabling the comboBox and setting the text.